# Is "home goal" an eggcorn of "own goal"?

Tags: sports, eggcorn

I used to think when a player put the ball in his own net it was called a *home goal* because that's what the older kids in school called it.  Then at some point I noticed that TV commentators were actually saying *own goal* and it was abbreviated *o.g.* on the score sheet.

It's obvious to even the most casual football fan that a *home goal* is one scored by a team on their home ground but the erroneous usage is quite common, for example in [this](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1230402/EPHRAIM-HARDCASTLE-Piers-Morgans-scores-home-goal-Thierry-Henry-comment-leads-Irish-heritage-claim.html) newspaper headline:

> Piers Morgan's scores home goal as Thierry Henry comment leads to Irish heritage claim [sic]

So, does *home goal* qualify as an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)?

Comment: The Daily Mail is capable of anything. However, I'm not sure this counts as an eggcorn because the goal at the defenders' end of the pitch might be considered to be the 'home goal'. But then I know little of football.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Eggcorn Hunt Club](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=12963820626&topic=6599&post=32380) thinks so, but concludes:

> It's difficult to Google for other examples of this eggcorn, since 'home
>   goal' has at least two non-eggcorned senses as well: a goal scored by a
>   player at their team's home ground, and a small goal designed for use in
>   the garden of one's home. "home goal" on Google gets about 108,000 ghits,
>   and the first hundred all seem to be examples of one of these two
>   non-eggcorned senses.

[Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=home%20goal,own%20goal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) suggests "own goal" antedates "home goal".

Reports containing *home goal* usually refer to a goal scored at the home ground. But you can find examples of both used in the same newspaper report.

For example, a headline says ["Another home goal for Newcastle owner"](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/city-news/2008/01/22/another-home-goal-for-newcastle-owner-115875-20294192/), and the article says "Football shirt-wearing Newcastle United owner Mike Ashley scored another own goal in the City yesterday." Normally reporters don't write headlines; it's possible the copy/sub-editor got it wrong.

So in general, yes, *home goal* is an eggcorn for *own goal*, if it means a player scores a goal against his own team.

Comment: Also of note is that 'home goal' does not require semantic acrobatics to interpret as a metaphor of 'own goal' (*home* is a thing that you call your *own*). For a term to be an eggcorn it is required that the phrases or words should be unrelated.

Comment: @Unreason: Agreed. I've said much the same thing in my comment  on the OP's question

Comment: @Unreason It's not a requirement that the words should be unrelated but that the replacement should be plausible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Comment: @z7sgѪ, I see - it seems I failed to grasp the concept. Thanks.